# how many loops is this running? - java coding

Tags: java, for-loop

I have been given "10 broken loops" to solve. I need to comment what was changed to make them correct.

I have

```
public class BrokenLoops {

  //loop 5 times
  public static void loop1() {
    for (int i = 1; i != 10 ; i += 2) { //final statement i += 2 means i+2
      System.out.println("In loop "+i);
    }
    System.out.println("Out of loop");
  }
```

I know what the problem is, it will never be 10. 1 then 3 then 7 then 9 then 11 etc.

What I don't know is how many loops will be run if I type either !=9 or !=11

Would the code run as

If the code has !=11, would it run as

```
i = 1 "in loop"
1 = 3 "in loop"
i = 5 "in loop"
i = 7 "in loop"
i = 9 "in loop"
i = 11 "out of loop"
```

and so, there are 6 loops? The correct answer for 5 loops would be !=9?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: the first code I posted is wrong. It should loop 5 times. Should it be !=9 or !=11 for 5 loops?

Thanks

Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: @mikeeustace if one of the answers helped you out, please accept one of the answers

Comment: if your only requirement is to run the loop 5 times why don't you change your loop itself? Something like `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` would work

Answer (score 3):

This loop have condition to run when i is not equal 10. Because i starts at 1 and increases by 2 on every iteration, i will be always odd number and therefore can newer equal 10. So condition for loop will be always true. Simply put: your loop will go indefinitely.

### About for statement from

The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is satisfied. The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

- The **initialization** expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
- The **termination** expression is invoked before each iteration. When it evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
- The **increment** expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

More info about for statement: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

//edit
Correct code for 5 loops if you have to use '!=' comparison would be:

```
for(int i = 1; i != 11; i += 2)
// i==1 PASS
// i==3 PASS
// i==5 PASS
// i==7 PASS
// i==9 PASS
// i==11 FAILED, Loop ends here
```

although it's better to use

```
for(int i = 1; i < 10; i += 2)
//or
for(int i = 1; i < 11; i += 2)
```

this way, your loop will end after 5 loops and safer for many reasons

Comment: Thank you @Ján Stibila 

I know the first code is broken. To fix it so it runs for 5 loops, should it be i != 9 or i != 11?

Thank you

Comment: Just edit my answer and add correct code for 5 loops

Answer (score 2):

The loop as you have posted will run continuously as `i` will never get the value 10.

- if you make the termination condition `i != 9` then the loop will run for 4 times.
- if you make the termination condition `i != 11` then the loop will run for 5 times.
- if you make the termination condition `i <= 10` then the loop will run for 4 times.

to get it to run 10 times, change the for loop to this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    //Your code
}
```

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i != 11; i += 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("In loop {0}", i);
}
Console.WriteLine("Out loop");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer @RFerwerda

i != 11   is 5 loops!

Thanks again

Comment: Could you run the code for me (added to the initial question)?

I get infinite in loop 1

Thanks

Comment: I've added code and output. Though I didn't write it in Java but in C# as I do not have a Java compiler at hand. The output must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible ways to solve your question.

**Example 1**

If you only need to get in the loop 5 times you can simple change your code to:

```
//loop 5 times
public static void loop1() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    System.out.println("In loop "+i);
  }
  System.out.println("Out of loop");
}
```

This will print something like:

> In loop 0
>
> In loop 1
>
> In loop 2
>
> In loop 3
>
> In loop 4
>
> Out of loop

---

**Example 2**

Another option would be to change your termination value to **!=11**(Just don't forget, that if you increment would become **i += 3** for example, this will become an infinite loop again):

```
public static void loop1() {
  for (int i = 1; i != 11 ; i += 2) { //final statement i += 2 means i+2
    System.out.println("In loop "+i);
  }
  System.out.println("Out of loop");
}
```

This will terminate the loop once i will be equal to 11, so the output would be:

> In loop 1
>
> In loop 3
>
> In loop 5
>
> In loop 7
>
> In loop 9
>
> Out of loop

---

**Example 3**

You can also change termination to **i < 10**(or <=9 or <=10 or <11):

```
public static void loop1() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 10 ; i += 2) { //final statement i += 2 means i+2
    System.out.println("In loop "+i);
  }
  System.out.println("Out of loop");
}
```

The output will be same as in **Example 2**.

---

**Example 4**

You can also add a check inside your loop to stop it after something evaluates to **true**:

```
public static void loop1() {
  int checkInt = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i != 10 ; i += 2) { //final statement i += 2 means i+2
    if (checkInt == 5) break;
    System.out.println("In loop "+i);
    checkInt++;
  }
  System.out.println("Out of loop");
}
```

So when *checkInt* will be equal to 5(loop was made 5 times), the loop will just stop. Output is the same as in **Example 2** and **Example 3**

Answer (score -1):

> If the code has i !=11, would it run as

You just have to use i<10 to get the desired result

Comment: so i < 10 means 5 loops.

Why would i !=11 not work? 

isn't that five loops when i = 1,3,5,7 and then 1 x out of loop?

As you can guess from my question, I'm very much beginnning :)

Thanks

Comment: because The first time i is 1, so when checked by the middle statement i != 11, it would be false as i is not equal to 11. and loop would not run a single time.

Comment: i != 11 should work too. it is just that we are used to working with < in the middle of statement.